# When moving records from staging, what options are there to merge?

Tags: merge, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

My ETL current scenario is as follows:

- For each pair identical tables dbo.T and staging.T

  - Delete from staging.T
  - Extract from remote web service and Load to staging.T
  - For each row in staging.T
  - dbo.T has PK?

    - Yes, update
    - No, insert

My primary area of doubt is surrounding the maintenence of the column lists.

The MERGE statement seems to be the best option but it does not seem to have the ability to update an entire row.  Thus, I find it is required to maintain long lists of:

```
Target.Column1 = Source.Column1, 
Target.Column1 = Source.Column1,
..., 
Target.ColumnN = Source.ColumnN
```

I found this [code generating template](http://devjourney.com/blog/using-t4-to-generate-sql-merge-scripts/) to assist with the merge, but I am extremely curious to know if there are standard approaches to the issue I just described or, more importantly, am I missing some part of the big picture - i.e. my approach is wrong.

Put another way, if a professional ETL developer were doing this (assuming they would be) how would they go about it?

I guess the goal I'd like to attain is a reliable way to change the schemas of my tables and not have an error prone process of updating all the lists of column copying.

To make in more concrete, here's a screen capture of the SSIS task and the schema for the first 4 tables I've implemented.

[image]

Comment: Where you say 'dbo.T has PK?
Yes, update
No, insert' Which table are you inserting to dbo.T or staging.T?

Comment: In the past I've resorted to building stored procedures to build the MERGE statements based on metadata stored in the database. The SQL can then be executed from another stored procedure. It is not easy to do and it is fairly fragile so I'd be interested to hear of any other approaches too.